# Temporal table like functionality for SQL server 2014 or older version

Tags: sql-server-2014, cdc, change-tracking, temporal-tables, historical-db

Is it possible to create temporal table kind of a functionality to keep history of frequently changing records in SQL server 2014 or older versions. I need to track historical changes in a table (E.g, part X was out of stock for Y number of days in Z period in Inventory table given part number and the date when it is received)